Using being with different adjectives
When do we use being with adjectives?

He is being calm and slow

He is being angry and sad

He is being lazy and beautiful


Is 1 correct because we can choose to be behave in that way whereas 2 where we have feelings something we can't really control that much "being" doesn't work? In 3 "lazy" works but "beautiful" not it is a state rather than action or behavior. Makes sense?

Beautiful does not describe a feeling or type of behaviour. You would not say "She is being tall and slim"

You are right. He is being [adjective] usually means 'he is behaving in a certain way'. If the adjective describes what a person is like, it's not appropriate to use being.

my explanation with examples is correct?

Is my explanation with examples correct? Yes - I told you 'You are right'.

Normally you'd use being {adjective} to describe a momentary or transitory situation, as distinct from saying that the person's nature is to be {adjective}

You're just being stubborn and refusing to admit that she's right.
She's being crafty to invite them to the meeting.

You could paraphrase this usage as

It is stubborn of you to refuse to admit that she's right.
It is crafty of her to invite them to the meeting.

